# I'm stuck with Backpropagation in my own CNN (FIXED)

Tags: c#, neural-network, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

Please help me, my CNN don`t predict hard written numbers from MNIST dataset, where is my mistake?

I'm writing my own CNN in C# without any external libraries because I want to understand how neural networks work. But now I am faced with the problem that during training, regardless of the learning rate, the filter values on the first convolutional layer tend to negative values (for example from .05 to -2.1) or less, and the neural network itself seems to be frozen and does not even change the prediction when the input data changes.

To begin with, I’ll say that basically I figured out how the convolution takes place and, in principle, how the neural network works, but understanding the backpropagation of an error became a real test for me.

The fact is that when I receive the error vector from the layers of the perceptron, I convert it into a tensor of the dimension of the output tensor of the last convolutional layer, then I perform the inverse operation of pooling, multiply each value by the derivative, and as a result I get a tensor ready for reverse folding.
Before this convolution, I find the gradient for the filters by convolving the input tensor in this layer and the error tensor.
Next, I apply this gradient to the filters and the error tensor to the bias. This is where it seems to me that the main problem of the inoperability of my neural network bias, because I do not fully understand how to update the bias.

**UPD:** I saw that if i don't apply bias to tensors in convolution method, freezing of cnn after first back propagation don't happened.

**UPD2:** Also i found a main formula for kernel update, but don`t understand how solve problem with different tensor depth. For example input tensor have 1 dimention, 16 filters on layer have same with input tensor count of dimentions, but error tensor, that come from previous layer, have 16 dimentions thats why change some parts for my situation.

```
 Filters[filter][channel] = learningRate * (Filters[filter][channel] - rot180(conv(IncreaseChannels(X, dZ.channels)[channel], dZ[channel], Filters[filter].Bias[channel]))
```

**UPD3:** I finaly fixed freezing prediction after applying bias, but anyway, prediction and back propagation, i think, dont work correctly. Whatever i do, CNN dont start predict correctly. (I training my network on MNIST dataset)

**UPD4:** Maybe i found my mistake and she was in Perceptron. U may see that my previous method of weights updator takes errors from current layer, but should take from previous.

Before fixing:

```
         for (var j = 0; j < Weights.Body.GetLength(0); ++j)
            for (var k = 0; k < Weights.Body.GetLength(1); ++k)
                Weights.Body[j, k] -= Neurons[k] * NeuronsError[j] * learningRange;
```

After:

```
         for (var j = 0; j < Weights.Body.GetLength(0); ++j)
            for (var k = 0; k < Weights.Body.GetLength(1); ++k)
                Weights.Body[j, k] += Neurons[k] * previousErrors[j] * learningRate;
```

**P.S.** *Yeah, after that fixing prediction dont freeze after back propagation and every time gives different value. But this value is strange. For example right was 4, predicted was 3, in the next turn right was 7, predicted was 4. What I mean is that the predicted value seems to be behind the correct one.*

I'm showing the main code here:

Main back propagation method:

```
public void BackPropagation(double expectedAnswer, double learningRange) {
            try {
                for (var i = 0; i < PerceptronLayers[^1].Neurons.Length - 1; i++) 
                    if (i != (int)expectedAnswer) 
                        PerceptronLayers[^1].NeuronsError[i] = -PerceptronLayers[^1].Neurons[i] * 
                                                                  NeuronActivate.GetDerivative(PerceptronLayers[^1].Neurons[i]);
                    else PerceptronLayers[^1].NeuronsError[i] = (1.0 - PerceptronLayers[^1].Neurons[i]) * 
                                                                NeuronActivate.GetDerivative(PerceptronLayers[^1].Neurons[i]);

                for (var i = PerceptronLayers.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                    PerceptronLayers[i].NeuronsError = PerceptronLayers[i].Weights.GetTranspose() * PerceptronLayers[i + 1].NeuronsError;
                    for (var j = 0; j < PerceptronLayers[i].Neurons.Length; j++)
                        PerceptronLayers[i].NeuronsError[j] = NeuronActivate.GetDerivative(PerceptronLayers[i].NeuronsError[j]);
                }
                
                for (var i = 0; i < PerceptronLayers.Length - 1; ++i)
                    PerceptronLayers[i].SetWeights(learningRange, PerceptronLayers[i + 1]);
                
                var errorTensor  = new Vector(PerceptronLayers[0].NeuronsError).AsTensor(
                    ConvolutionLayers.Last().Output.Channels[0].Body.GetLength(0),
                    ConvolutionLayers.Last().Output.Channels[0].Body.GetLength(1), 
                    ConvolutionLayers.Last().Output.Channels.Count);

                for (var i = ConvolutionLayers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    var inputTensor     = ConvolutionLayers[i].Input;
                    var prevErrorTensor = inputTensor;

                    prevErrorTensor = Pooling.BackMaxPool(prevErrorTensor, ConvolutionLayers[i].NotPooled, 
                        Configuration.ConvolutionConfigurations[i].PoolSize); 
                    prevErrorTensor = NeuronActivate.GetDerivative(prevErrorTensor);
                    
                    var originalFilters = ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters;
                    var extendedInput = inputTensor.GetSameChannels(prevErrorTensor);
                for (var f = 0; f < ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters.Length; f++) {
                    for (var channel = 0; channel < ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[f].Channels.Count; channel++) {
                        var filterGradient = Convolution.GetConvolution(extendedInput.Channels[f],
                            prevErrorTensor.Channels[f], 1, ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[f].Bias[channel]);
                        ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[f].Channels[channel] -= filterGradient.GetFlip() * learningRate;
                    }
                    
                    for (var bias = 0; bias < ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[f].Bias.Count; bias++) 
                        ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[f].Bias[bias] -= prevErrorTensor.Channels[bias].GetSum() * learningRate;
                }
                
                errorTensor = Convolution.GetConvolution(Padding.GetPadding(prevErrorTensor.GetSameChannels(ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[0]), 
                    (ConvolutionLayers[i].Filters[0].Channels[0].Body.GetLength(0) - 1)/2), originalFilters, 1);        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show($"{e}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Forward propagation methods:

CNN Layers:

```
public Tensor GetNextLayer(Tensor layer) {
        Input = layer;
        var nextLayer = new Tensor(new List<Matrix>());
        
    nextLayer.Channels.AddRange(Convolution.GetConvolution(layer, 
    Filters, ConvolutionConfiguration.Stride).Channels);
        nextLayer = NeuronActivate.Activation(nextLayer);

        NotPooled = nextLayer;
        Output    = GetMaxPooling(nextLayer);
        
        return Output;
    }
```

FNN Layers:

```
public double[] GetNextLayer() {
        var nextLayer = new Vector(Weights * Neurons) + new Vector(Bias);
        return NeuronActivate.Activation(nextLayer);
    }
```

Convolution method:

```
private static Matrix GetConvolution(Matrix matrix, Matrix filter, int stride, double bias) {
            var xFilterSize = filter.Body.GetLength(0);
            var yFilterSize = filter.Body.GetLength(1);
            
            var matrixSize = matrix.Body.GetLength(0);
            var conMat = new Matrix(matrixSize - xFilterSize + 1, matrixSize - yFilterSize + 1);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < conMat.Body.GetLength(0); i += stride) {
                for (var j = 0; j < conMat.Body.GetLength(1); j += stride) {
                    var subMatrix = matrix.GetSubMatrix(i, j, i + xFilterSize, j + yFilterSize);
                    conMat.Body[i,j] += (filter * subMatrix).GetSum() + bias;
                }
            }
            
            return conMat;
        }
        
        public static Tensor GetConvolution(Tensor tensor, Filter[] filters, int stride) {
            var newTensor  = new Tensor(new List<Matrix>());

            for (var i = 0; i < filters.Length; i++) {
                var tempMatrix = new Matrix(tensor.Channels[0].Body.GetLength(0) - filters[0].Channels[0].Body.GetLength(0) + 1,
                tensor.Channels[0].Body.GetLength(0) - filters[0].Channels[0].Body.GetLength(0) + 1);

                for (var j = 0; j < tensor.Channels.Count; j++) {
                    tempMatrix += GetConvolution(tensor.Channels[j], filters[i].Channels[j], stride, filters[i].Bias[j]); 
                }

                newTensor.Channels.Add(tempMatrix); 
            }
                                
            return newTensor;
        }
```

LeakyReLU function:

```
private static double Activation(double value) => value switch {
    < 0 => value * .0001d,
    _   => value
};
```

Derivative method:

```
    public static double GetDerivative(double value) => value > 0 ? value > 1 ? 1 : value : .0001d;
```

Channel changing for two tensors with different count of channels:

```
public Tensor GetSameChannels(Tensor reference) {
        var newTensor = this;

        if (newTensor.Channels.Count != reference.Channels.Count) {
            newTensor = newTensor.Channels.Count < reference.Channels.Count
                ? newTensor.IncreaseChannels(reference.Channels.Count - newTensor.Channels.Count)
                : newTensor.CropChannels(reference.Channels.Count);
        }

        return newTensor;
    }

    private Tensor IncreaseChannels(int channels) {
        var tensor = new Tensor(Channels);
        for (var i = 0; i < channels; i++) tensor.Channels.Add(Channels[^1]);
        return tensor;
    }
    
    private Tensor CropChannels(int channels) {
        var matrix = new List<Matrix>();

        for (var i = 0; i < channels * 2; i += 2) {
            matrix.Add(Channels[i]);
            for (var x = 0; x < Channels[i].Body.GetLength(0); x++) {
                for (var y = 0; y < Channels[i].Body.GetLength(1); y++) {
                    matrix[^1].Body[x,y] = Math.Min(Channels[i].Body[x, y], Channels[i + 1].Body[x, y]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return new Tensor(matrix);
    }
```

Weights of filters after teaching without bias:

```
-997,3155 -997,3192500000001 -997,2990000000001 -997,3140000000002 -997,3402500000001 -1044,7554999999998 -1044,7914999999998 -1044,7344999999998 -1044,8004999999998 -1044,7464999999997 -1067,75425 -1067,8045 -1067,7737499999998 -1067,7984999999999 -1067,791 -1079,0785 -1079,0425 -1079,0755 -1079,0462499999999 -1079,0964999999999 -1087,373 -1087,30775 -1087,3385 -1087,3055 -1087,355 -7,9106939999999994 -7,927943999999999 -7,953443999999999 -7,969193999999999 -7,946693999999999 -8,290214 -8,304464000000001 -8,286464 -8,338964 -8,322464 -8,472092 -8,531341999999999 -8,469842 -8,493841999999997 -8,508841999999998 -8,593831999999999 -8,563832 -8,560082 -8,591581999999999 -8,562332 -8,678007999999998 -8,627007999999998 -8,639757999999999 -8,677257999999998 -8,630007999999998 -0,005331552000000016 -0,026331552000000008 -0,019581552000000016 -0,039081552 -0,019581552000000016 -0,048117712 -0,021117712000000004 -0,033867712000000015 0,0006322879999999822 0,002132287999999983 -0,03234073600000001 -0,0030907360000000067 -0,045090736 -0,018840736000000004 -0,040590736 -0,018812656000000018 -0,047312656 -0,003812656000000013 -0,045062656 0,0029373439999999945 -0,056092064000000004 -0,046342063999999995 -0,015592064000000003 -0,050842064 -0,066592064 0,042989347584 0,029489347583999997 0,030239347583999997 0,073739347584 0,033989347584 .......
```

Comment: If your coefficients spiral out of control during backpropagation, carefully check that you have negative feedback not positive.  A single flipped sign will prevent convergence.

Comment: @BenVoigt on the first layer of the perceptron I have negative neural error values, but on the last layer, before cnn, these values are positive, due to the multiplication PerceptronLayers[i].NeuronsError[j] *= NeuronActivate.GetDerivative(PerceptronLayers[i].NeuronsError[j ]); After that, all values in the error tensors are positive.

Comment: Have you done any sort of adaptive filter before?  The error update on adaptive linear models is easier to understand, I'd make sure you have that concept down before moving to non-linear neuron responses and hidden layers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Before this project, I am making a simple perceptron in which the weights and biases are updated with the neuron errors taken from the last layer by overlaying the expected response with the received response. But what seems to be convolutional neural networks, as I understand it, this is already a different level, which is why such questions arise.